# BestPractice: Displaying Months on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, html, date, bestpractice

Is this a good practice in displaying months?

Code Snippet:

```
<b>{!CASE( IF( (MONTH(TODAY()) +3) > 12,
               (MONTH(TODAY()) +3) - 12,
                MONTH(TODAY()) +3),
                 1, "January",
                 2, "February",
                 3, "March",
                 4, "April",
                 5, "May",
                 6, "June",
                 7, "July",
                 8, "August",
                 9, "September",
                10, "October",
                11, "November",
                    "December")}</b>
```

I'm using this in outputting the current month, previous month, next month of the current month, and so on. As you can see in the code snippet, the code is for the third month forward of the today's month. I realized this might not be a good approach. If this can be minified in different approach, it would be better, I would not be creating unnecessary line of codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) and then format the date using the oracle [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) syntax

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MMMM}">
        <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

> UPDATE based on your edited question

you can use the same approach to display the month in text for any date you want by changing the value of apex:param

for example, you can apply your first part of the formula in the param value like

```
   <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MMMM}">
        <apex:param value="{!DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),IF((MONTH(TODAY()) +3) > 12, (MONTH(TODAY()) +3) - 12,MONTH(TODAY()) +3),DAY(TODAY()))}" /> 
   </apex:outputText>
```

or

if you are using a custom / extension controller for your VF page, you can have a controller variable which can use addMonths method on Today() to give you the dynamic date you want and you can simply bind the apex:param value to the controller variable

**Controller**

```
public Date dynamicDate {
 get { return Today().addMonths(3); }
}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MMMM}">
        <apex:param value="{!dynamicDate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: I haven't checked the links that you gave yet. But first, I want to ask, could this be used when you want to get the previous and current month of today's month or getting the month after next month?

Comment: Its not good to change the question after its answered (it makes the answer invalid). I have updated my answer based on your updated question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I did that to make the question more descriptive. I appreciate your effort in editing your answer to satisfy my question.

Comment: no worries.. hope now its helpful for you :-)

Comment: Yes! Your answer really helped me. :-)